# How to remove similar images based on hog features?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have 5000 images and each image can generate a vector with about 1000 dimensions(hog feature), but some of the images are very similar so I want to remove the similar ones. Is there a way to achieve this?

===============================================================

As @thedarkside ofthemoon suggested, let me explain a little bit more about what I am trying to do. I am using SVM + HOG features to do image classification. I have prepared some training data but some of the training images are very similar so that I want to remove the similar ones to reduce computation cost. I don't know if the removal of similar images has a side effect on the final classification rate so a good criteria of 'similarity' must be found. That's what i am trying to do.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Random-I-Am I am trying cosine similarity but it is on going and I don't know how the result will be

Comment: And I don't know why someone down vote this question, isn't it a reasonable question on stackoverflow?

Comment: What do you mean similar? Visually? In HOG space? Why would you do something like this, explain yourself a little, maybe it is a wrong thing to remove the similar ones.

Answer (score 0):

In another way(not using hog features) you can compute [color histogram](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_comparison/histogram_comparison.html) for each image and compare against others.

Like,

1. Get the first image and compute the histogram,
2. Now for each other images calculate histogram and [compare](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?highlight=comparehist#comparehist) with the first one.

If you find close match on the histogram you can discard it. And by using `CV_COMP_CORREL` you will get match in the range of 0-1.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends what you mean by similar, currently my favorite image similarity descriptor is the gist descriptor.

http://people.csail.mit.edu/torralba/code/spatialenvelope/

but it is not in opencv.  however it is coded in C here, so can be added to a c++ project (extern "C"), if your using the c++ opencv, not sure about python sorry.

http://people.rennes.inria.fr/Herve.Jegou/software.html

I have found this to be pretty good, and quite efficient.

(Sorry this is not a direct opencv solution, but i feel it is a reasonable answer as gist C code can be added to c++ project, and works nicely.)

EDIT:
if you just want to remove ones with similar hog descriptor you can use the:
http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/k_nearest_neighbors.html
or
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/flann/doc/flann_fast_approximate_nearest_neighbor_search.html